# "Rather!" meaning 'yes'

Tags: word-usage, usage, british-english

> Rather - exclamation (Chiefly British)

> Meaning: certainly; yes:
> "Do you want to come out for dinner with us this evening?" "Rather!"

Some dictionaries give the meaning of *'rather'* as *'certainly, yes, emphatically yes'*.
Is this a common use of 'rather'?
Can I use it in every situation in which I want to say '*yes*' emphatically?
Is it commonly used in British English?

Comment: 1. Said with emphasis on the second syllable. 2. Not in common use. 3. Obsolete since about 1930. 4. Confined to a small section of society when it was in use.  5. Will cause laughter if presented as 'typically British'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You seem more knowledgeable than me, but I don't think it's "obsolete," you don't hear it every day but you do from time to time.

Comment: I would only say "Rather!" if i were channelling a 1920s upper-class buffoon, e.g. while taking part in amateur dramatics. I would no more say it in normal, non-ironic speech than I would call someone 'old bean' or 'old fruit'.

Comment: You might as well have an American say 'Bully!", like Teddy Roosevelt et al.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would bother asking whether something is commonly used in British English, if you are only going to insist that the British English speaker is wrong when they (correctly) tell you that is not commonly used owing to being old-fashioned / almost obsolete.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu - voting to close. Opinion based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exclamation "Rather!", said with the accent on the second syllable, signifying enthusiastic agreement, is severely dated. It was briefly popular in the 1920s among the British (and, among them, mainly English) upper classes. It would be considered very old fashioned by many modern British speakers, and will be found mainly in the Wooster and Jeeves novels of PG Wodehouse, and, possibly, modern novels set in the period 1910-1930, although some writers have reservations. A modern novelist discusses the use of 1920s period dialogue:

> At first I really wanted to have my characters using plenty of slang
>   from the time. Then I started looking at the things people actually
>   said in 1920s Britain.
>
> I say! Rather! I should think so! Jolly decent. A good sort. Old
>   thing. Old bean. Old man. Ragging. Blighter. What rot! What a lark!
>   That's torn it!
>
> Nowadays we can't read these phrases without hearing them in the voice
>   of Bertie Wooster or Billy Bunter. They sound flippant, innocent,
>   comical and bit twee.

[An Interview with Frances Hardinge](http://awfullybigblogadventure.blogspot.com/2014/08/an-interview-with-frances-hardinge-by.html)